# Drag And Drop Entity Framework ObjectSets in WinForms

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-5

In WinForms 4.5, I add a EntityModel from a database.

Then, in the DataSource window, I can see the Entity Sets.  However, it does not allow me to drag and drop them onto a Form.

If I create a Proxy class which just has

```
List<Customer> {get;set;}
```

Then I can view this in the DataSource Window and drag and drop.

Is the issue that the Designer is only looking for IList<>, not ObjectSet<>?

Am I doing something wrong or just the way it works in VS12?

Comment: [This walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076) (using DbContext) manually binds to the sets.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good walkthrough that I had not see before.  I would mark it as answer if I could.